# Problem passing id using useParams() to Carousle

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

[image]this is the code in which I am getting id using useParams() but when we try to access it inside the carousel it is throwing an error that says "invalid hook call". Firstly I used match.prams.id but it is deprecated now

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from "../../actions/productAction";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ProductDetails = ({}) => {
    let { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
        (state) => state.productDetails
      );
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getProductDetails(id));
      }, [dispatch, id]);
    
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <div className="ProductDeatils">
            <div>
            <Carousel>
            {product.images &&
                  product.images.map((item, i) => (
                    <img
                      className="CarouselImage"
                      key={item.url}
                      src={item.url}
                      alt={`${i} Slide`}
                    />
                  ))}
            </Carousel>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };

export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: How is `ProductDetails` component rendered?

Comment: <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails/>} />

Comment: Ok, then I see no issue with the code you've shared. Are you sure the hook issue is with this code? Or is this issue coming from the `Carousel` component being used? Can you share your `package.json` file so we can see your app's dependencies?

Comment: See I have added the screenshot in the post

Comment: `react-material-ui-carousel` has a dependency on [React ^17.0.2](https://github.com/Learus/react-material-ui-carousel/blob/master/package.json#L58) so you need to roll back your React version from 18 to 17 or find a new carousel package to use in the meantime until they update their code.

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/Learus/react-material-ui-carousel/issues/174) for React 18 compatibility from 6 days ago when React18 went live.... but I guess that person didn't feel the need to fork the repo, make the change, test, and open a PR. ‍♂️  [Someone else did though](https://github.com/Learus/react-material-ui-carousel/pull/175).